# How to protect powershell file, and call single function

Tags: powershell

I'm having this problem for a while now and google have its limits.
I'm writing a powershell file that contain several generic function.
I use the function in vary scripts and now I want to let other personal in my work to use them as well.
the problem is, do to sensitive operation, I want to lock and protect the script (compile to a dll, exe etc').
how do I create powershell library like C# DLL?

one option I try but did not find out how to continue is to compile the script using powerGUI to executable file ( .exe) but then I canot access the function in it let alone pass on parameters to that function.

hope you understood me :)

thank you.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to "protect"? Passwords?

Comment: password, user validation, servers name and file location.
basically some of the script logic.

Comment: If you grew into a need for library, create a .NET project instead.

Comment: @Neolisk A PowerShell module would also work, and be a bit easier to distribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't. Rather than trying to obscure this information (if you compile them, they can be decompiled and your "protected" resources will no longer be), remove them entirely and make those **parameters** for your functions. This both protects your "sensitive" data and makes the code much more reusable.

You can then package your functions into a [module](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/an-introduction-to-powershell-modules/)